# Delayed response from jQuery (with some other odd artefacts)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a mind-boggling response from jQuery that I'm hoping someone can help me with. I have a simple problem ... I'm setting the "value" of a HTML form's hidden field (aka, `<input type='hidden'>` when the form loads. I have a form with three hidden fields and two are working just fine. The third ... well here's the problem:

Once the form has completed loading (and yes it has loaded and is visible ... as indirect proof the previous two hidden fields have loaded and successfully been set by jQuery), I run the following code (just showing relevant snippet as this final field is a date set to "today"):

```
case "today":
    SetFieldValue (targetElement , Date.today().toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") );
    console.log ('Setting ' + jQuery(targetElement).attr('id') + ' to "today": ' + Date.today().toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") );
    break;
```

The SetFieldValue is a little function I wrote to allow setting DOM elements regardless of what type it was. The code is follows:

```
function SetFieldValue ( domObject, value ) {
  // as a safety function, check if a string representation of the domObject was passed in and convert it to a jQuery object if it was
  if ( jQuery.type(domObject) === "string") {
    domObject = jQuery(domObject);
  }

  if ( jQuery.inArray (domObject.prop('tagName').toLowerCase(),['input' , 'select' , 'textarea']) >= 0 ) {
    console.log ("setting to value attribute: " + value);
    domObject.attr('value',value);
    console.log ("now set to: " + domObject.attr('value') + "(" + domObject.attr('id') + ")" );
  } else {
    console.log ("setting to html attribute");
    domObject.html( value );
  }
  return domObject;
}
```

Please note the console.log messages as this is important in understanding the craziness of the problem. When I run this, here's what I get on the console:

[image]

Now I set a breakpoint at the last line of the "today" case statement (aka, on the "break;" line). Based on the console messages all is well. It appears the DOM element #activity-start_time has been set. Well here's where it gets weird.

The first thing I do is test the reference to "targetElement" and the first thing the debugger console give me is an empty array:

[image: empty set]

What? That's pretty odd. While I'm pondering that a few seconds pass and all of sudden it resolves itself to what I'd expect (I don't retype it into the console it simply changes from the empty set to what you see below):

[image: and now for something completely different]

Now that the targetElement is exactly as I'd expect I do a simple check with jQuery that the DOM element of #activity-start_time is reporting the same value. You can see the result above. It's precisely the same as targetElement except it HAS NOT got a value. What?!?

I'm at a complete loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ken

p.s. I will note that other people have suggested using .prop instead of .attr both seem to behave precisely the same.

Comment: You're not turning targetElement into a jQuery object `SetFieldValue (targetElement`

Yet you do for the logging... This seems to be odd and could be causing issues with your code.

Comment: @jeff I'm not sure what you mean. I check at the top of the function whether what has been passed to me is a "string" and if it is then it is converted to a jQuery object. In most cases -- and in this case in particular -- the object passed in is already a jQuery object.

Comment: but what if it's a DOM object that's not been jQueried? you seem to wrap it in the logging explicitly, but not when it has been passed in directly. Possibly/probably not your issue, but it may be safer to have your function accept an ID, which then gets selected directly in a jQuery selector at the top of the function. Just an idea. May be worth putting some logging in your === "string" block to see if it's getting hit or not.

Comment: Ok, i did that but it just validated that the object sent into the function is already a jQuery object.

Comment: Might be of interest that that same function, when called again later interactively (by pressing a button) but with precisely the same values ... works. I'm now looking for a tall building to jump from. ;^)

Comment: Which browser are you using to debug with? Sometimes, it does make a difference :/

Comment: May i ask why you dont use `JQuery("#activity-start_time").val()` ?

Comment: @Dementic, I tried that as well. No difference in behaviour.

Comment: The question was since i as one, would not mix jquery with javascript, just to be on the safe side. your code is jumping from one to the other, and that is an opening to trouble.

Comment: Really @Dementic? I am trying to just use jquery. Where do you see javascript that should be jquery? If I make the assignment object = $(this); and then use the call object.attr('id') that's still jquery, right?

Comment: Just simple questions but I ask it : where is you javascript? Is it at the begining or the end of you page definition? I your code running in a `Document.Ready()` function? Just to be sure all is really loaded.

Comment: Yes all code is in a document.ready() function. The particular code in question is executed when a jQuery trigger is fired at the completion of the AJAX form loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I didn't provide enough context for people to really dig into this problem but I have in the end solved it. What was the issue? It was silly really ... isn't always? Anyway it was just a case of the DOM element in questions 'id' not beging unique. Grrr. It's always the obvious things that you then go onto overlook that get you in trouble.

Anyway, thanks for your patience and help.